# HTTPCookieStorage still has cookies after reinstalling macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview, httpcookie

I have a macOS application that logs a user in with an `WKWebView`
what I’m seeing is that, if the user has deleted the app and then reinstalls at (when running from Xcode) is that there are still values in HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies - anyone know why that may be?